# Links generated in email (click.email.xyz.com) starts with http://

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-tracking

The tracked links generated in the email start with http://. I would like to know if I can change it to https:// so that browser's insecure link warning can be avoided.

I tried to stumble upon the documentation. Unfortunately, I am unable to find anything related to this configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an SSL Certificate configured on your account. In case you don't have one, you can purchase it from SFMC.

> SSL Certification Functionality
>
> Most clients require two SSL
> certificate configurations to completely secure all pathways in their
> Marketing Cloud account.
>
> One certificate is used to secure CloudPages, legacy landing pages,
> and URLs and **links within emails** via DigiCert. One certificate is used
> to secure Content Builder images, Portfolio images, and content hosted
> with Akamai.

Check this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ssl_certificates.htm&type=5) for more information

Comment: Thank you Rachid!